# Entity manager @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) - how can I make it use toString()?

Tags: java, enums, ejb, ejb-3.0, entitymanager

The ratings column in the (MySQL) database has type `ENUM('G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17')` (notice the dashes). This:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
public class Movie implements Serializable {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Rating rating;

    public static enum Rating {
        G("G"), NC_17("NC-17"), R("R"), PG("PG"), PG_13(
                "PG-13");

        private String label;

        private Rating(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { // added but still
            return label;
        }
    }
}
```

causes a `Data truncated for column 'rating' at row 1` exception for NC_17("NC-17") (and PG_13("PG-13"), works for the other values) -  nevermind the exception should read `Data rejected for enum ENUM('G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17') for column 'rating' at row 1`.

This happens because it tries to insert the string NC_17 - I thought that adding `toString()` as above would fix this but apparently calls `rating.name()` to produce the string to insert (instead of  `rating.toString()`).

Are there any workarounds or do I have to change the type of ratings to `ENUM('G','PG','PG_13','R','NC_17')` in the DB ?

Edit: from the comments - what I ask is why JPA is not calling toString() for an @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) entity field on update ? So I can't put in the db arbitrary chars ? It seemed like an oversight to me but apparently it is not - so off for mysql

Comment: Hibernate allows defining your own type, which would use toString() (and an additional fromString() to read the entity state from the database), but if you have the option of using underscores in the DB, then do that: it will be much simpler.

Comment: @JBNizet: " defining your own type" as in `@Enumerated(EnumType.MYTYPE)` ? Still won't it call `name()` (which is final) ?  Do you thing that this is a bug in JPA (glassfish4 on eclipse, I have no Hibernate persistence) - toString returns name() by default

Comment: No EnumType is an enum containing only STRING and ORDINAL. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom

Comment: @JBNizet: thanks. Any reason JPA is not calling `toString()` for an `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` entity field ?

Comment: name() is guaranteed to always return the same thing, whereas toString() can be overridden to return whatever you like. So JPA wouldn't have a completely safe way of finding the enum value given its string representation. I haven't found in the specs that name() MUST be used, but it's the safest choice.

Comment: @JBNizet: did not find docs on this unfortunately either. You mean the problem with `toString()` is that this string must be passed to the enum constructor (be its only argument at that) for the pattern to make sense ? Are you too lazy to pack the gist of those comments to an answer :D ?

Comment: No. Hibernate can't invoke an enum constructor, otherwise it wouldn't be an enum anymore. What I'm saying is that you could override toString() in the enum and make it return, for example, the current time. It would thus be impossible, from the value stored in the database, to go back to the enum value. name() is final and can't be overridden, so it doesn't have this problem. You asked about JPA, not Hibernate specifically, that's why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @JBNizet: I fully understand this. What I tried to say is that (finally) JPA because of it all (no way to enforce the constructor arguments of an enum) chooses to use `name()`. You did answer my question (finally) which was indeed on JPA (did mention Hibernate till you did), so please :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JPA uses the `name()` of the enum, and not what is returned by `toString()` which could be overridden and return something different every time it's called. `name()` doesn't have this problem, because it's final and is thus guaranteed to always return the same thing.

So, your simplest option is to rename the values in your database so as they match with the enum names.

If that's really not an option and you're using Hibernate, then you could [define your own type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom), that would be used to transform the enum to a String and vice-versa by Hibernate.

Comment: And toString may not be reversible while hibernate needs to reverse the conversion with Enum valueOf(String)

Comment: It would be nice if JPA enforced you to override valueOf() when overriding toString() and used valueOf() to get values from the DB - dunno