# Hibernate Paramater Value did not match expected type with Enum

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using hibernate criteria to create a basic select equal expression on an Enumeration field.

The class

```
  @Column
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private StateEnum state;
```

The expression

```
Object value = StateEnum.PENDING;
this.criteriaBuilder.equal(this.root.get("state"), value);
```

I'm using value as Object because in real code I have a String and need to convert this String to the field instance with reflection.

After some debug I checked that:
 Hibernate QueryParameterBindingValidator has some validation, and the important here is:

```
else if (expectedType.isInstance(value)) {
```

In my case, this expression is returning false, but checking with IntelliJ tools expectedType is StateEnum:

[image]

And value is StateEnum also:

[image]

But the isInstance comparation return false

[image]

With one base test:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class clazz = StateEnum.class;
    Object value = StateEnum.PENDING;

    if(clazz.isInstance(value)) System.out.println("isInstance");
    else System.out.println("not isInstance");

  }

}
```

Return "isInstance" because validation is true.

If I force the method return to true on hibernate validation class than hibernate return resultSet like a charm, anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Some version informations:
 Hibernate-core: 5.4.15
 Spring-boot: 2.3.0.RELEASE
 spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: 2.3.0.RELEASE

Comment: will this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759197/entity-manager-enumeratedenumtype-string-how-can-i-make-it-use-tostring

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when the information can easily be communictated using plain text.

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I´m still having this issue, when I run locally I can´t do the validation but for any reason when I run in a container work fine.

Comment: Hey man, did you find a solution to this yet ? I'm having the same problem ^^

Answer (score 0):

This error means the types are different.

Unfortunately you didn't post a screenshot of debug output from `value.class` on
`else if (expectedType.isInstance(value)) {`
line
Are those enums perhaps of the same name, but from different packages?

Note, for other people with a this kind of exception - most common way to get this kind of error is defining query method with wrong type of parameter, for example a String.